# MySQL database of english words?

Tags: php, mysql, dictionary

I'm looking for a list of English dictionary words for a password application I'm working on.
Ideally the list can be easily inserted to a mysql database.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22):

Most Unix systems have a set of word lists, in my Ubuntu system it is on /usr/share/dict/american-english

A single word comes per line, so it's easy to insert if you really want it in a database.

This bash oneliner does it inefficiently:

```
cat /usr/share/dict/american-english \
    | while read i; do echo insert into wordlist\(word\)  VALUES \(\"$i\"\); done \
    | mysql -u<user> -p<pass> <db>
```

This MySQL command does it efficiently (if the file is in the same machine):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/usr/share/dict/american-english' INTO TABLE wordlist;
```

Comment: My system also has a file called `cracklib-small` in `/usr/share/dict/`. It contains 53k words while the American English file has 99k words. While cracklib is smaller, the English file contains words like `émigré` which would be terrible for passwords, so if the goal is diceware style password generation, you may want to use the cracklib dictionary instead.

Answer (score 20):

For importing a word list to MySQL, use

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/usr/share/dict/words' INTO TABLE words;`

where `words` is a single-column table.

Comment: Just to add for anyone that googled here: to insert it in a multi-column table you can use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/usr/share/dict/words' INTO TABLE words (column);` where column is a varchar field you want to store the words in.

Comment: My dict folder was empty, so I needed to download the words `apt install wamerican`

Answer (score 5):

http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

I found this : [MySQL formatted english words list](http://www.4redpixels.com/uploads/words.sql)

dunno much about how many words are not in but it's a huge list anyway :)

There are about 128/129K words in it and words longer than 10 letters have been removed.